# is it possible for $\dfrac {1} {x} $ to be smaller than every positive real number but still bigger than $0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers

According to the  $ε-δ$ definition of Limits, $\lim _{x\rightarrow +\infty }\dfrac {1} {x}=0$ means there always exists  a real number $M $ such that for all real $x>M > 0$ implies $\dfrac {1} {x} < ε$ for every real $ε > 0$.

Since there always exists $x>0$ satisfying $\dfrac {1} {x} < ε$ for every real $ε > 0$, does this also mean it is possible for $\dfrac {1} {x} $ to be smaller than every positive real number but still bigger than $0$?

Comment: No, your reading of the quantifiers is wrong. For every $\varepsilon$, there exists $M$ ($M$ depends on $\varepsilon$). I suggest you write, at least in a first time, explicit dependencies in the quantifiers: $\forall \varepsilon \exists M_\varepsilon \text{s.t. } \forall x> M_\varepsilon \dots$

Comment: @ClementC. Yes, $M$  does depend on $ε$, but what does this bother here?

Comment: As http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2013822/75808 implies, this means that at the end of the day, you do *not* have any positive $x$ such that $1/x<\varepsilon$ simultaneously for all $\varepsilon$. The set of such $x$'s will be $\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} (M_\varepsilon, \infty)$.

Comment: @ Sorry, but I still cannot understand why I would end up with having no  positive $x$ such that $1/x<ε$ simultaneously for all $ε$, please explain more, thanks !

Comment: A oncrete example: here, you have $M_\varepsilon = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$. The set $S$ of real numbers $x$ such that $x> M_\varepsilon$ simulatenously for *all* values of $\varepsilon > 0$ will be $S=\bigcap_{\varepsilon > 0} (1/\varepsilon,\infty) = \emptyset$.

Comment: @ClementC. $1/\varepsilon<\infty$ for   every real $ε>0$, how could the intersection of all these  non-empty nested intervals $(1/\varepsilon,\infty)$ become empty ?

Comment: n is finite for any fixed integer n, yet the sup of all integers n is infinite.

Answer (score 3):

No.  M depends on $\varepsilon$.  To make $1/x$ smaller than smaller and smaller $\varepsilon$, you will have to make $M$ larger and larger.

Answer (score 1):

No.  No matter how large $x$ is, there will always be infinitely many positive real numbers smaller than $\dfrac1x$.

For example, $\dfrac1{2x}$ is positive and is smaller than $\dfrac1x$.

More generally, $\dfrac1{nx}$ is positive and smaller than $\dfrac1x$, where $n$ is a positive integer such that $n > 1$.

Most generally, $\dfrac1{rx}$ is positive and smaller than $\dfrac1x$, where $r$ is any real number such that $r > 1$.